# function get_the_date() not returning properly date

Tags: php, wordpress

im building a theme using wordpress. On the archive.php im using these conditions to display the appropriate title. The category and tag are working, but the date not. I dont know what im doing wrong.

Any help will be welcomed.

```
if ( is_category()) { 
    single_cat_title();
} elseif ( is_tag()) {
   single_tag_title();
} elseif ( is_day()) {
    get_the_date();
} elseif ( is_month()) {
    get_the_date();
} elseif ( is_year()) {
    get_the_date('Y');
} else {
   echo "Not found";
}
```

Comment: What's not working? Is nothing being output or is the output incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function get_the_date() needs to be echoed.

Youre doing great, just need to echo the date function

```
if ( is_category()) { 
    single_cat_title();
} elseif ( is_tag()) {
   single_tag_title();
} elseif ( is_day()) {
    echo get_the_date();
} elseif ( is_month()) {
    echo get_the_date();
} elseif ( is_year()) {
    echo get_the_date('Y');
} else {
   echo "Not found";
}
```